# Is there a single word to denote "arguments on words, word meanings, and their registers"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

I often get into **arguments** with my colleagues on the difference between formal and informal words.

> Example: He was ***felicitated*** on ***bagging*** the first prize.
>
> I tried to explain to my colleagues that the above sentence is an
>   example of mixing a heavy formal word (felicitation) with an informal
>   word.(bagging)

My question is - "Is there a **single word** to denote such **arguments** **on words, their registers or their meanings.**

Comment: Do you mean a literal argument between two people where the subject of the argument is words or that there is a figurative argument, disagreement or conflict between words or phrases as in the case of your example?

Comment: How about "EL&U"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A term  (rare)  is ***[logomachy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/logomachy):***

> - An argument about words. (ODO)
> - (Linguistics) argument about words or the meaning of words (AHD)

Origin:

> - Mid 16th century: from Greek logomakhia, from logos 'word' + -makhia 'fighting'.

Answer (score 3):

Semantics, is often used when arguing word meaning...That is what it is - the branch of linguistics associated with meaning.